# Testing function that starts file download with jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I'm trying to test this function with JEST library (I'm using also enzyme in the project), but I completely stuck.

Describing this function in a few words, I use it to export previously prepared data. I machine some data and then pass it in the form of a single string, which this func wraps into a single text file and starts a download.

Mostly, it's csv, tsv and text.

```
/**
 * Function creating text file and starting download process
 *
 * @param name - file name
 * @param extension - file extension
 * @param content - file content
 */
export const downloadTextFile = (name: string, extension: string, content: string) => {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.className = 'download-helper';
    link.download = name + '.' + extension;
    link.href = `data:application/${extension},` + escape(content);
    link.click();
};
```

I want to develop good testing habits, so I'm also trying to understand edge cases like this one here. Any tips on how to start it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This function is not that easy to test because it does not return any value and performs side effects. A solution to this is using jest spies to mock the `createElement` function. Example : https://codesandbox.io/s/6xp9lqjzk3

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know if I would figure out anything like that, thanks! Testing is great and actually gives you a lot of sense of confidence, but testing such features are really painful, at least for me.